# In Mozilla Firefox, the placeholder is working but issue on pressing esc key

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events, placeholder

First I tested support by:

```
function SupportsInputPlaceholder() {
    var i = document.createElement("input");
    return "placeholder" in i;
}


$(document).ready(function(){       
    if(!SupportsInputPlaceholder()) {
        alert("no support");
    }
}
```

So the alert did not pop up.

But in on clicking on the input field with placeholder and pressing <kbd>escape</kbd>, the placeholder text becomes the permanent textbox text. This does not happen in Chrome.

To resolve this I tried the following code on document load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    if(!SupportsInputPlaceholder()) {
        alert("no support");
    }
    $("[placeholder]").keyup(function(e) {      
          var i = $(this);
          var placehold;
          placehold = i.attr("placeholder");   // this line has problem
      
          if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    
              alert("placeholder is " + placehold);
              if (i.val() == i.attr("placeholder"))  {
                  i.val("");                
              }
          }
    });
```

So on printing  `alert("placeholder is " + placehold);` The placehold value contains ""
Should not the  `i.attr("placeholder")` return the placeholder text?

Comment: *"But in on clicking on the input field with placeholder and pressing escape, the placeholder text becomes the permanent textbox text."* Not for me: http://jsbin.com/ovoruk/1 (source: http://jsbin.com/ovoruk/1/edit) Firefox 20 on Ubuntu

Comment: *"Should not the i.attr("placeholder") return the placeholder text ?"* It does: http://jsbin.com/ovoruk/2 (source: http://jsbin.com/ovoruk/2/edit)

Comment: What is the code you are using ?

Comment: @ Anubha: THose are links to JSBin. If you move your mouse over the page, you'll see "Edit" in the upper right-hand corner. But your code works as well: http://jsbin.com/ovoruk/3 (source: http://jsbin.com/ovoruk/3/edit)

Comment: it works in chrome, but not in mozilla

Comment: @ Anubha: I read your question. I'm testing in Firefox, see above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thankyou, It is working for me in firefox in jsbin, but not in my project, I think it may be due to warning Undefined attribute name (placeholder) in eclipse ? Its just printing "placeholder is" in alert box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resolved if I replace "js/jquery.min.js" src I was using with "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" src

So the project was using own placeholder functionality code which has problems and not the jquery placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has an error:

```
if (i.val() == i.attr("placehold"))
```

That should be

```
if (i.val() == i.attr("placeholder"))
// -----------------------------^^
```

Comment: Crowder I did the change, thankyou, but the alert box is still printing "placeholder is", I explained what I think in my last comment

Comment: @Anubha: *"but the alert box is still printing 'placeholder is'"* Of course it is, we didn't change *that* code.

Comment: but I ran the code I just edited in my question. The line : alert("placeholder is having " + i.attr("placeholder"));

Comment: I just posted how I resolved the problem, Thank you very much for your help.